# Applying custom css class using TWIG and SCSS Mixin (Style not applying)

Tags: css, debugging, sass, twig, include

Good morning,

This has been quite a brain turner for me, learning Twig and Scass at the same time. I'm sure this fix is a simple line of code adding or removing somewhere, but since I do not understand how it works, I cannot understand how to fix it. With the current code the TWIG Include is appling the class 'Opacity_20' (or Opacity_40 etc) as selected. However this class is supposed to change the background style - but its not.

Below is the snip of HTML of the include and where the custom class will apply

```
<div class="info-container {{ white_opacity }}">
   <div class="tite-container">
      <h1 class="title">{{ title|raw }}</h1>
   </div>
```

Below is the SCSS for the div - I removed all other styles for ease of reading

```
.info-container{
   

    &:before{
        
    }

    &:after{
        
        @include white_opacity;
```

'white_opacity' is the include in question

```
{% include 'include/banner.html.twig' with {
        'title': 'Unplaceables',
        'subtitle': 'Placeholder subtitle...',
        'text': 'Lorem ipsum ',
        'background':  '/img/banners/roadshow/roadshow-banner.jpg',

        'white_opacity': 'opacity_20'
    }
%}
{% endblock %}
```

Below is the SCSS that is applying the class but not the style

```
@mixin white_opacity{

}

@mixin opacity_20 {

        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.20); 
        @include white_opacity;
}

@mixin opacity_40 {
    @include white_opacity;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.40);
}

@mixin opacity_60 {
    @include white_opacity;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.60);
}

@mixin opacity_80 {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.80);
        @include white_opacity;
}
```

Comment: Still having an issue here, someone told me i should bounty the question but i am not sure how

Comment: You don't have enough reputation yet to offer bounties, but when you do you should see the link just below 'Add comment'. You can refer to the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have misunderstood a crucial thing about `mixin`s: they don't generate any output unless explicitly `include`d, so your compiled stylesheet doesn't have any `opacity_*` classes defined, since those are `mixin`s themselves. That's why it isn't applying any style: it doesn't match any selector.

You would have to change your scss to:

```
@mixin white_opacity {
}

.opacity_20 {
/*...*/
}
```

However, mixins are **reusable** code blocks, an empty mixin doesn't do anything. Mixins are just like functions and can also receive parameters to change the output, that's precisely what you want here.

```
@mixin white_opacity($opacity: 100) { 
    /* Solid white if invoked without arguments */
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.01 * $opacity);
}

.opacity_20 {
    @include white_opacity(20);
}

/* Other styles */
```

But you can also apply [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principles and generate all your classes in one go using other dynamic features of scss.

```
/* Define all styles to generate */
$transparencies: 20, 40, 60, 80;

@each $value in $transparencies {
  .opacity_#{$value} {
    @include white_opacity($value);
  }
}
```

You can read up on [variables](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables) and [loops](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control) in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your input, really appreciate it